# What is the point of using EventHandler like that?

Tags: c#, event-handling

What is the use of unregistering event handler that is not added yet in the code below?

```
public class foo 
{
    private event EventHandler<boo> booCompleted;

    public RegisterBooCompletedHandler(EventHandler<boo> newBooCompletedEventHandler, bool forceUnregisterOtherEventHandlers)
    {
        if (forceUnregisterOtherEventHandlers) 
            booCompleted = null

         booCompleted -= newBooCompletedEventHandler;       // <- why do we unregister not added yet event handler?
         booCompleted += newBooCompletedEventHandler;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is probably to make sure there is no pre-existing event handler associated with that event, before adding one, or in this case, make sure booCompleted has no existing link to newBooCompletedEventHandler. (Happens if RegisterBooCompletedHandler is somehow called twice by mistake)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that if you call `RegisterBooCompletedHandler(handler)` multiple times with the same handler, you still only actually subscribe to the event *once* for that handler.

My guess is that *actually* you've seen this due to someone working round a problem where really they were subscribing to the event in the wrong place, and so subscribing multiple times... but I'm sure there are *some* cases where it's hard to know whether you've already subscribed or not, and just making it a (nearly) no-op to subscribe again is convenient.

I say it's a "(nearly) no-op" because it changes the ordering. Consider:

```
// After this call, invocation list is A
RegisterBooCompletedHandler(A, false);
// After this call, invocation list is A, B
RegisterBooCompletedHandler(B, false);
// After this call, invocation list is A, B, C
RegisterBooCompletedHandler(C, false);
// After this call, invocation list is A, C, B
RegisterBooCompletedHandler(B, false);
```